# Deserialization in Java not working consistently across multiple methods

Tags: java, file

I am getting an error when creating a FileInputStream in the 
`deletebook()` method. But the same object creation works in the
`searchBook()` method. Does anyone know why the code yields different results when the only thing differing are the parameters passed to the methods?

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMain {
    public static final String FILENAME = "cool_file.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Application");
        ObjectOutputStream oos1;
        int sel = 0;
        TestMain t = new TestMain();
        do {
            System.out.println("1) addSubject");
            System.out.println("2) addBook");
            System.out.println("3) deleteSubject");
            System.out.println("4) deleteBook");
            System.out.println("5) searchBook");
            System.out.println("6) searchSubject");
            System.out.println("7) Exit");
            System.out.println("#############");
            System.out.println("Insert a selection");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            sel = s.nextInt();

            switch (sel) {
            case 1:
                t.addSubject();
                break;
            case 2:
                t.addBook(fos);
                break;
            case 3:
                t.deleteSubject();
                break;
            case 4:
                t.deleteBook(fos);
                break;
            case 5:
                t.searchBook();
                break;
            case 6:
                t.searchSubject();
                break;
            case 7:
                t.exitService();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
            }

        } while (sel != 7);

    }

    public void addSubject() {
        System.out.println("In addSubject"+"\n");
        }

    public void addBook(FileOutputStream fos) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("In addBook"+"\n");
        long bookId;
        String title;
        double price;
        Integer volume;
        LocalDate publishDate;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        System.out.println("Enter Book ID");
        Book b=new Book();
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        bookId=s.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Enter the Title of the Book");
        title=s.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the price of the Book");
        price=s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the Volume of the Book");
        volume=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the publishDate of the Book");
        String dateStr_1=s.next();
           DateTimeFormatter formatter_1=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
            publishDate= LocalDate.parse(dateStr_1,formatter_1);
            b.setBookId(bookId);
            b.setTitle(title);
            b.setPrice(price);
            b.setVolume(volume);
            b.setPublishDate(publishDate);

            oos.writeObject(b);
            //fos.close();
            //oos.close();

    }


    public void deleteSubject() {
        System.out.println("In deleteSubject"+"\n");
    }

    public void deleteBook(FileOutputStream fos) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("In deleteBook"+"\n");
        System.out.println("Enter the Book Id to be deleted");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int bookId=s.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Book> results = new ArrayList<Book>();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        System.out.println(fis);
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);
            System.out.println(fis);
            while (true) {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                results.add((Book) ois.readObject());
            }
        } catch (EOFException ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
            // as expected
        } finally {
            if (fis != null)
                fis.close();
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }
        System.out.println("results = " + results);
        for(Book b:results)
        {
        if(b.getBookId()==bookId)   
        {
            results.remove(b);
        }
        }

        File file = new File(FILENAME);

        if(file.exists())
        {
            file.delete();
            System.out.println("File Exists");
            if(file.exists())
                {
                System.out.println("File Exists after deletion");
            }
        }
            if(file.delete())
        {
            System.out.println("File deleted successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to delete the file");
        }

        /*ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        for(Book newb:results)
        oos.writeObject(newb);*/


    }
    public void searchBook() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In searchBook"+"\n");
         ArrayList<Book> results = new ArrayList<Book>();

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);
                while (true) {
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                    results.add((Book) ois.readObject());
                }
            } catch (EOFException ignored) {
                // as expected
            } finally {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            }
            System.out.println("results = " + results);

    }
    public void searchSubject() {
        System.out.println("In searchSubject"+"\n");

    }
    public void exitService() {
        System.out.println("Thank You for using the service..You rare now Exitinng the service");

    }
}
```

> This is the console:
>
> Welcome to the Application 1) addSubject 2) addBook 3) deleteSubject
>   4) deleteBook 5) searchBook 6) searchSubject 7) Exit
>
> ####### Insert a selection 2 In addBook
>
> Enter Book ID 1 Enter the Title of the Book ufihv Enter the price of
>   the Book 1 Enter the Volume of the Book 1 Enter the publishDate of the
>   Book 01-01-2001 1) addSubject 2) addBook 3) deleteSubject 4)
>   deleteBook 5) searchBook 6) searchSubject 7) Exit
>
> ####### Insert a selection 2 In addBook
>
> Enter Book ID 2 Enter the Title of the Book 2 Enter the price of the
>   Book 2 Enter the Volume of the Book 2 Enter the publishDate of the
>   Book 02-02-2002 1) addSubject 2) addBook 3) deleteSubject 4)
>   deleteBook 5) searchBook 6) searchSubject 7) Exit
>
> ####### Insert a selection 4 In deleteBook
>
> Enter the Book Id to be deleted 1 null
>   java.io.FileInputStream@7106e68e java.io.EOFException Finally results
>   = [Book@1a6c5a9e, Book@37bba400] File Exists File Exists after deletion Failed to delete the file 1) addSubject 2) addBook 3)
>   deleteSubject 4) deleteBook 5) searchBook 6) searchSubject 7) Exit
>
> ####### Insert a selection  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(Unknown Source)     at
>   TestMain.deleteBook(TestMain.java:124)    at
>   TestMain.main(TestMain.java:49)

Comment: why are you deleting file instead of an object which is serialized ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, why are you deleting file, which has serializable state of your objects. So, when you delete the file, which has serializable state of your object. You will loose everything even file won't exist. And, if you try accessing same file in some other method, you will get exception.

Also, when you deleted a specific object, you aren't saving the latest updated state of your object to file (you didn't serialized latest state of object) instead you are directly deleted the file. Then, what is the point of remove objects from deserialized object ?